# Session Management of a java base REST web application in a clustered environment

Tags: java, session, rest, cluster-computing

I have this requirement, i need to implement java base RESTful web service in a clustered environment. my problem is how do i manage the user sessions here. Once a user logged in, he should be able to perform all the available actions without a problem, also a user should be able to keep a shopping cart for him. What is the best approach for this? Any code samples to do this? please note main factors to be identified are,

1. RESTful web application in a clustered environment.
2. Multiple clients will be used this application. (Eg: Android, Apple, Web..etc)
3. user should be able to keep a shopping cart (Dont know whether this violates the RESTful concept)
4. Runs in Jboss 6.0.0

Answer (score 1):

RESTFul applications don't use sessions so there should not be any problems using a clustered environment.  RESTful applications send authentication credentials on every request.

Comment: Darrel Thanks. Do you mean that i have to make an additional DB call to validate the user for each request? Or should i generate generate some kind of session key and keep in a map so for each request i can easily validate the user without calling the db?

Comment: @bluelabel If your standard auth mechanism is not fast enough to do on every request then you could provide the client with a token that it could send in future requests to make the auth faster.  Whether the token has user info encrypted into it, or whether it expires, etc are all factors of how secure and how fast your system needs to be.

Comment: Darrel thanks, Could you please explain me bit more about this token authentication, well so far what i ve done is, once a user successfully logged in, i create a token manually and send it with the response, any requests from this user will have this token wrapped in it. so how do i validate using this token? i really do not want to make a DB call for each request to validate the user. Could you please help me on this with the way i ve done it so far?

Comment: @bluelabel  Here is an example http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-bearer-04

Answer (score 1):

There's no problem with having a shopping cart in a RESTful web service. It's just that the shopping cart won't be stored with the session as some typical applications do. In this case, you'll want a shopping cart resource:

`/app/rest-api/shopping-carts/204314`

All devices could access this resource and see the same data. Since the web server is stateless (shopping carts are stored in a database), clustering isn't a problem. I don't know of any particular problems JBoss would have doing this. I would guess none, since JBoss implements all the functionality from the Servlet spec (or at least enough to facilitate what you need here.

In terms of authenticating users and associating them with carts, that is a much bigger topic, with a lot of dependencies on information you haven't provided. For example, do you have access to an OAuth provider? Alternately, are you considering the OpenID route? Is user authentication information already stored in your application somewhere? what does that look like?

Comment: The shopping cart data could also be maintained by the client.

Comment: Thanks Nathan, well authenticating seems to be the main problem iam having now. As this app should provide user to log in either using their own account created for this app or using there face book account. If facebook is chosen, then authenticating should be happened through my java server. What i dont understand is, if a user used either of those, how do i validate him for each request he makes other than login in a clustered environment? As Darrel suggested, should i authenticate the user for each request? What are the options i have for this?

Comment: @Darrel Miller - Yes, the shopping cart can be maintained by the client. The shopping cart can't be maintained by the client if he wants all devices for each user to show the same shopping cart, or if reporting on shopping cart contents would be important (what items went into a shopping cart w/o being bought?). There are obviously trade-offs in how this is designed.

Comment: @bluelabel - You should look into Facebook's OpenID authentication, since that would not force you to handle Facebook credentials. OpenID uses a token-based mechanism, and you could do the same in this case (as suggested above by Darrel).

In this case, you'll just need to authenticate the user, generate a token and push the user, token and a timestamp into the database. (token as primary key). Then every request would use that token to identify the user.

There may be other ways to do authentication, but they will be variations on the two themes here: user/pwd on every request or token-based.

Comment: Nathan, thanks, forget about the restful concept, is there any other way to authenticate the user for each request other than querying the db? iam not allowed to use spring security here, what Iam allowed to get from Spring framework is, its MVC support only.

Comment: There are many ways to authenticate users other than using a database. Here are a few off the top of my head: OpenID, OpenAuth, file on the filesystem, LDAP, Kerberos, etc. Which to use depends on what you're doing. If I were you, I would research each one and make a preliminary decision. Once that decision is made, start some implementation. Once you run into trouble, figure it out using google. If google fails, come back to stackoverflow and open a new question with the details of your problem.